# How to display python output in a tkinter popup

Tags: python-3.x, time, tkinter

My code calls for a program to start installing. The information of the install like how far it is in downloading and what is being downloaded is displayed in the python output area (where a `print("stuff")`goes). Is there a way that I can scan everything being displayed into the output box and update my tkinter window every second to show that?

Example Code:

```
def install_display(self):
    print("INSTALL STARTED")
    self.sleep(1)

    *code to get the display*

    self.root.update()
```

[image: This is what I see and want to be displayed into a tkinter window (just the text)]

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of ways to do that. The easiest is probably to use the `pexpect` module to start the install, and periodically call `child.read_nonblocking()`.

Comment: I looked this up and it seems like this just saves everything that is being output. I want it to be live, not just a big dump at the end

Comment: @Thomas It is live. I've used it to monitor and provide a UI for a video encoding process.